# C# How to remove specific value from different class LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, class, contains

I want to remove some values from my class **Type**

```
public class Type
{
    public double Power { get; set; }
    public double Current { get; set; }
}
```

These 2 public variables are getting values from my **Form Form1** and im accessing them like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Type> Win = new List<Type>(); 
    Poker.Type sorted;
}
```

Whenever i want to actually add new value to **Power** or **Current** i do it like this

```
Win.Add(new Type() { Power = Power, Current = 1 });
sorted = Win.OrderByDescending(op => op.Current).ThenByDescending(op => op.Power).First();
```

After this is done i want to check if **Power** Contains let's say 500.If it does i want to remove it from `sorted.Power` and also from `List<Type> Win`. How can i do this using **LINQ** ?

Comment: Side note: I would suggest a name other than `Type` for your class, to avoid confusion with `System.Type`.

Comment: Yes, I know it's bad name but it's accurate in my case

Comment: Okay, regarding your actual question - can you clarify what you mean by "remove it from Type.Power"? Type.Power is a double, not a collection.

Comment: And does LINQ .Remove(sorted) won't work in your case? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry it's a mistake i meant to type sorted.Power

Comment: Win.Remove(500) doesn't work it should include some reference to the class "Type"

Comment: With `FirstOrDefault(t => t.Power==500)` you could get the first item with `Power==500` or `null`. Another way might be to use `Where()` when you fill "sorted". If the not wanted element is not added to the list, you don't have to remove it...

Comment: You can remove elements from a `List<Type>` but not from `Type`. The best you can do in `Type` is to set the values to `0.0`.